# python ignore whichever line that causes error and continue running the code after that line

Tags: python, error-handling

I understand the try/except method. What I'm trying to do is:

```
try:
    some_func1() #potentially raises error too
    do_something_else() #error was raised
    continue_doing_something_else() #continues here after handling error
except:
    pass
```

In the above code, when the error is raised at do_something_else(), the error is handled but then the try statement is exited.

What I want is for python to continue whatever code that is after the line that causes the error. Assuming that an error can happen anywhere in the try statement so I can't just wrap the try/except around do_something_else() itself, is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Include only `do_something_else` in your `try: ... except: ` block

Comment: You catch all exceptions, and then pass. Python is just doing what you're telling it.  (Complete example with traceback if you want more help).

Comment: or after it.  `try: <code that can throw> except: <handle exception>  do_other_stuff()`

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `finally`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do (try with restart) is not possible in Python. Lisp can do it (http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html), and you can implement it in Scheme using `call/cc`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code that you want to do after the possible exception after the except.  You may want to use `finally` (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for the documentation):

```
try:
    some_func1()
    do_something_else() #error was raised
except:
    handle_exception()
finally:
    continue_doing_something_else() #continues here after handling error or if no error occurs
```

if `continue_doing_something_else()` can also throw exceptions, then put that in a try/except too:

```
try:
    some_func1()
    do_something_else() #error was raised
except:
    handle_exception1()
try:
    continue_doing_something_else()
except:
    handle_exception2()
finally:
    any_cleanup()
```

as a general rule, your exception handling should be kept as small in scope as possible while remaining sensible, consider excepting only the 'expected' exceptions and not all of them (e.g. `except OSError:` when attempting to open files)